# How to monkey patch a function executed during import

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a package A using a function in a package B.

A is running a function c imported from B:

```
#B code
def c():
    # code that can't be executed during tests

#A code
from B import c
c()
#c is executed every time A is imported
```

Now, i need to monkeypatch c during the unites tests.
The problem I am facing with monkey patch is that package A is imported when I run the following code:

```
def test(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setattr("A.c", lambda x: "dummy")
```

How can I do that without modifying package A's code. I thought about adding an environment variable in code A to detect test mode. The idea is to not call function c during test mode. Unfortunately, this is not a clean solution at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A module is only loaded during the first import at runtime.

To mitigate your issue, you can first import module `B` and monkeypatch `c()` before importing `A`.

```
import B
B.c = lambda: print("monkeypatched")

import A
```